# Priority queue with both decrease-key and increase-key operations

Tags: data-structures, priority-queues

A [Fibonnaci Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Summary_of_running_times) supports the following operations:

- `insert(key, data)` : adds a new element to the data structure
- `find-min()` : returns a pointer to the element with minimum key
- `delete-min()` : removes the element with minimum key
- `delete(node)` : deletes the element pointed to by `node`
- `decrease-key(node)` : decreases the key of the element pointed to by `node`

All non-delete operations are $O(1)$ (amortized) time, and the delete operations are $O(\log n)$ amortized time.

Are there any implementations of a priority queue which  also support`increase-key(node)` in $O(1)$ (amortized) time?

Comment: @Raphael if you **increase** the key of the minimum element so that it is now the largest key, it's not immediately obvious (at least to me) that you don't have to do a super-constant amount of rebalancing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume you have a priority queue that has $O(1)$ `find-min`, `increase-key`, and `insert`. Then the following is a sorting algorithm that takes $O(n)$ time:

```
vector<T>
fast_sort(const vector<T> & in) {
  vector<T> ans;
  pq<T> out;
  for (auto x : in) {
    out.insert(x);
  }
  for(auto x : in) {
    ans.push_back(*out.find_min());
    out.increase_key(out.find_min(), infinity);
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: I had assumed that `(de|in)crease-key` only did plus or minus one.

Comment: And does there exist a DS that allows increase-key operation in constant time but decrease in logarithmic (or more)? (For a min-heap)

Comment: @GonzaloSolera: The impossibility proof in this answer doesn't care about decrease-key; O(1) find-min, increase-key, and insert are already a problem together (and the proof's dependence on insert isn't really necessary; O(n) heapify is enough, or we can probably reuse the same heap over multiple sorts to prove it violates comparison sort bounds regardless of the cost of heapify or insert).

Comment: Okay sorry, I missed read that. Thanks for your comment!